# logdet maximization under logdet inequalitie constraint

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control

Consider the following convex problem
$\max_{\mathbf{A}} \log |\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{CA} |$ subject to $\log |\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{FA} | \leq \xi$ where $\mathbf{A}$ is a semidefinite positive matrix and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix.

Does exist any closed form solution to $\mathbf{A}$? If not, does exist efficient algorithms to solve this  problem?

Thanks in advance,

Mikitov

Comment: I am curious as to whether the problem is really convex. The determinant is log-concave for positive definite arguments, and maximization of a concave function is equivalent to the minimization of a convex function -- so that's ok; however, your constraint is concave. Can you tell us anything about $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{F}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant your constraint *may be* concave, not *is* concave.

Comment: Also, I think it is possible that the problem will not have a simple closed-form solution. If you consider the KKT system for this problem, the inequality constraint will induce complementarity constraints ($\mu \cdot (\log |\mathbf{I} + \mathbf{FA} | - \xi) =0$), which need to be resolved algorithmically. 

Comment: $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{C}$ are meant to be herminitian.

Yes, being rigourous the optimization problem is

$\min_{A} \log | \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{FA}|$ subject to $\log | \mathbf{I} + \mathbf{CA}| \geq \epsilon$ and also $\mathbf{A}$ being semidefinite positive. Can this problem be casted as a convex problem?

Ok about the closed form solution.

Thanks,

Mikitov

Comment: Off-hand, it seems to me that the problem is convex only if $\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{CA}\succ\mathbf{0}$ and $\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{FA}\prec\mathbf{0}$. If that is the case, you may be able to pose this as some kind of semidefinite program -- but that takes me out of my province. 